# Is a declaration an expression in SML?

Tags: expression, declaration, sml, ml

in SML, is a declaration (val-declaration, type declaration, ...)

- an expression
- a statement which, if I am correct, is defined as an expression with side effect
- or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: [This formal grammar](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/sml.html) has its own top-level entry for declarations. `dec` by itself is not an instance of `exp`. Andreas Rossberg  wrote that and is active on this tag, perhaps he could give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

A declaration is just that, a declaration, its own syntactic class. The only way to embed into an expression is via the expression form `let` *dec* `in` *exp* `end`.

Technically, there are no statements in ML.